# Linq and Contains

Tags: c#, linq, contains

First example which works:

```
public class Test
{
    public int ID;
    public string Name;
}

List<int> list1 = Load1();
List<Test> list2 = Load2();

var query = list2.Where(c => list1.Contains(c.ID));
```

Now I would like to use two lists of objects as a source and get list of objects that have this same values for member ID.

```
List<Test> list1 = Load2();
List<Test> list2 = Load2();
```

Below doesn't compile:

```
var query = list2.Where(c => **list1.ID.Contains**(c.ID));
```

I know it is wrong but placed it here for better understanding.
I would appreciate someone to show me the right path :-)

Regards
Mariusz

Comment: If only all edits were thanked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make your Test class equatable:

```
public class Test : IEquatable<Test>
{
  public int Id {get;set;}
  public bool Equals(Test other)
  {
    return this.Id == other.Id;
  }
}
```

Then this would work:

```
list1.Where(item => list2.Contains(item));
```

Comment: I like this answer most because lambda expression still looks clean and readable.

Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 6):

You can perform an [inner join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397941.aspx) as follows:

```
var query = from x in list1
            join y in list2 on x.ID equals y.ID
            select new { x, y };
```

or

```
var query = list1.Join(list2,
                       x => x.ID,
                       y => y.ID,
                       (x, y) => new { x, y });
```

Comment: Thanks. Works like a charm. I forgot that join will filter out IDs that are on left or right only.

Going forward (we have an intersect at the moment) how would you get something like .Except?

Comment: @aristo have a look at the final version on my answer, you can just replace the intersect line with an except line

Comment: @Bob, Yes I have missed that out. I can do all basic operations on these collections now. Awesome :-) thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

`enter code here`simple version would be

```
var query = list2.Where(c=> list1.Select(l=>l.ID).Contains(c.ID))
```

or you could use the linq version of an inner join if you have no repetition

```
var query = list2.Join(list1,a=>a.ID,b=>b.ID,(a,b)=>a);
```

or you could use a System.Collections.Generic.IEQualityComparer

```
public class TestComparerer : IEqualityComparer<Test> {
    bool IEqualityComparer<Test>.Equals(Test a, Test b) {
        return a!=null && b!=null && a.ID.Equals(b.ID);
    }

    int IEqualityComparer<Test>.GetHashCode(Test a){
     return a.ID.GetHashCode();
    }
}

var query = list2.intersect(list1,new TestComparer());
```

finally if you override Equals and GetHashCode() on test you can make them comparable

```
public override bool Equals(object o) {
var other=o as Test;
return other!=null && this.ID==other.ID;
}

public override int GetHashCode() {
return ID.GetHashCode();
}
```

again this will allow you to do `list1.Intersect(list2)` or `list2.Intersect(list1)`

Comment: var query = list2.Where(c=> list1.Select(l=>l.ID).Contains(c.ID)) looks quite readable as well as joins using lambdas simply make me cry :-) Thanks a lot Bob!

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
list2.Where(c => list1.Any(d => d.ID == c.ID));
```

You need to enumerate the other collection with your own code to get what you want, because .Contains uses the .Equals function, which for Objects will just match against the reference.

Comment: Very nice and clean example. Thanks Michael! I didn't know that there is so many ways of achieving that :-)